# php global variable doesn't work inside included file

Tags: php, global-variables, php-include

I've searched for a day to find a solution for this,But no luck yet,
I have a function called : `online()` this function is inside a file called `client.php` which is located in root/dir/includes/client.php:

#### In client.php:

```
// db connection
include "base.php";

// check if availabe
$available = "false";
$check = mysql_query("SELECT available FROM users ");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
    if($row['available'] == "yes") {
        $available = "true";
    }
}
// get config
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config ");
$config = mysql_fetch_array($fetch);

// functions
function online() {
// globals
global $available,$config,$path;

// build box

    if($available == "true") {
        ?>
        <div id="online">

        <?
    } else {
            ?><div id="offline"> <?
        }
echo 'client.php is included';
}
}

?>
```

#### About client.php:

first it establishes a database connection, then checks if a user is available, if yes : `$available = "true";`
else:
`$available = "false";`

Then I include `client.php`  in `index.php` (located in root), So i Have:

#### in index.php:

```
$path = "dir/";
include $path . "includes/client.php";
```

So far so good, everything works,

### The problem is...

I need to use this function in other pages in sub directories too, to be more specific, I'm trying to add this function to my wordpress website which is located in: root/wp
in my wordpress header I include `client.php` :

```
include "../dir/includes/client.php";
```

And I get the output , So i'm sure it is included, But, none of my global variables work when I open my wordpress (root/wp) resulting in `$available = null` while it is expected to be `"false"` as it is defined in `client.php`

The confusing thing is that, when I echo $available inside my wordpress header I can get the value, but when I echo it inside `client.php` it is null again, so if I echo both in wordpress header and `client.php` , when I open my wordpress page, I can see the one I included in header, and the other one inside `client.php` is null.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do not use the mysql_* functions anymore. They are deprecated. Switch to mysqli_* functions.

Comment: @TobiasKun Thanks, I'm no expert, should i just replace mysql with mysqli in the whole code?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) and if there are questions afterwards, ask them here :)

Comment: Was `$available` declared in the global scope? If your include script gets loaded in a function context, then it will reside in that functions context. And later attempts with `global $available` will naturally fail.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with a [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Try to use

```
$GLOBALS['available']
```

instead of

```
$available
```

in your client.php. So it will be defined in global scope.
At the definition section also:

```
$GLOBALS['available'] = "false"; and $GLOBALS['available'] = "true";
```

Comment: I've tried that before, same thing as defining globals inside the function

Comment: I mean also at the definition: $GLOBALS['available'] = "false"; and $GLOBALS['available'] = "true";

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the link reference in your include file. You could try:
`include "/rootfolder/dir/includes/client.php";` instead of include `"../dir/includes/client.php";` Also had a problem like this but this fixed it.